# Change authentication url in Quarkus' Swagger-UI

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, swagger-ui, openid, quarkus

Problem is, I'm starting the Quarkus service and a Keycloak in a docker-compose setup, where I need to configure the internal hostname and it won't be the same I will use to authenticate from outside.
In the following picture I want Swagger-UI to open the external url (`http://localhost:8180` in my case) instead of the internal docker-compose url (`http://keycloak:8080`).
[image: Swagger-UI with Auth]

Is there a config property available to change this? I don't not find anything matching and tried out some stuff, but was unsuccessful.

---

I'm starting the Keycloak server in devmode and mount a custom realm during file.

To the Quarkus service I set the following properties:

```yaml
    environment:
      QUARKUS_OIDC_AUTH_SERVER_URL: http://keycloak:8080/realms/WPLAT_dev-keycloak-realm
      QUARKUS_OIDC_CLIENT_ID: my-service
      QUARKUS_OIDC_CREDENTIALS_SECRET: secret
      QUARKUS_OIDC_TOKEN_ISSUER: http://localhost:8180/realms/WPLAT_dev-keycloak-realm
```

(`QUARKUS_OIDC_TOKEN_ISSUER` was needed or otherwise the returned tokens weren't accepted)